# How to make fgets stop reading from the keyboard

Tags: c

I am trying to run somebody's code and I am new to c so I have a problem with reading the input. The following loop read it from the keyboard, but when I am finished it doesn't stop

```
while (fgets(in_line, MAXLINE, stdin) != NULL ) {
    ...
}
```

Is there any kind of character that I have to enter to simulate 'NULL'? I've tried \0 but that doesn't seem to work.

I am very sorry, this problem has probably arisen tons of times, but I just cannot find a proper explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a NULL from `fgets` when it reaches EOF. From the keyboard, that's suually signalled with CTRL-Z (DOS/Windows and I think MacOS before X) or CTRL-D (Linux/Unix/MacOS X).

Comment: it says suspended and exits the program back to shell.

Comment: Actually, CTRL-Z in Linux/Unix doesn't exit to the shell, it puts the program in the background, stopped. If you then type either `fg` or `bg`, it will be started again, as a ForeGround or BackGround task respectively - quite handy at times.